# DataTable shows error in alert box while trying to load data on clicking a button

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using the latest 1.10.15 version of [Datatable](https://datatables.net/). The table will be filled with data when the  button with id `btn_search` is clicked.

HTML:

```
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id_trace</th>
            <th>mac</th>
            <th>dest_ip</th>
            <th>dest_port</th>
            <th>src_ip</th>
            <th>src_port</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>id_trace</th>
            <th>mac</th>
            <th>dest_ip</th>
            <th>dest_port</th>
            <th>src_ip</th>
            <th>src_port</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<button type="button" id="btn_search" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search">Search</button>
```

Javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   Table = $('#example').DataTable({
        data:[],

        columns: [
            { "data": "id_trace"  },
            { "data": "mac" },
            { "data": "dest_ip" },
            { "data": "dest_port" },
            { "data": "src_ip" },
            { "data": "src_port" }
        ],
        rowCallback: function (row, data) {},
        filter: false,
        info: false,
        ordering: false,
        processing: true,
        retrieve: true        
    });

        $("#btn_search").on("click", function (event) {

       $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index/fetch_info", 
                type: "post",

            }).done(function (result) {
                Table.clear().draw();
                Table.rows.add(result).draw();
                }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                      // needs to implement if it fails
                });
    });


     });
```

Inside `fetch_info`, I have :

```
$sql='SELECT `id_trace`,`mac`, `dest_ip`, `dest_port`, `src_ip`, `src_port` FROM `trace`';

        $sql='SELECT * FROM `trace`';


        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        $query_result=$query->result();// this codeigniter code
        merely holds an associative array

        echo json_encode($query_result);
```

I got this error in an alert box:

```
   DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown 
parameter 'id_trace' for row 0, column 0. For more information 
about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4
```

In the firebug , I can see the ajax response like this :

```
    [{"id_trace":"462036","mac":"e8:03:9a:0c:d0:06","dest_ip":"206.54.163.50",
    "dest_port":"443","src_ip" :"10.10.10.37","src_port":"54707"},{"id_trace":"462037",
"mac":"e8:03:9a:0c:d0:06","dest_ip":"104.193
    .36.37","dest_port":"80","src_ip":"10.10.10.37","src_port":"53544 {"id_trace":"462038",
"mac":"6c:b0:ce:85:50:01","dest_ip":"52.42.48.105",
    "dest_port":"80","src_ip":"10.10.10.38","src_port":"46944"},{"id_trace" .......
```

So how can I implement the data loading when the button is clicked ?

Comment: You have some serious errors in your JSON. Correct them and your code will work. Once cleaned up `Table.rows.add(result).draw()` works right away.

Comment: What errors do you see ? The json response is not shown fully in OP.  `.... ` is added at the rear.

Comment: 1) the json is produced through the PHP code ` echo json_encode($query_result);` . So what do i have to do here ? 2) If I add `dataType:json` in the ajax call, then the error alert does not show but the table is not loaded with data either.

Comment: I really dont know what you are missing, but if you pass a valid JSON with items you describe, then your clientside code actually works -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/932/**

Comment: If you can include the ajax call as well, that would be helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145797/discussion-between-istiaque-ahmed-and-davidkonrad).

Comment: @davidkonrad, I pointed out 2 issues - 1 and 2 .

Comment: I cannot debug your serverside code, but my guess is that the returned JSON (besides from being malformed)  also is enriched with orphans like line breaks, tabs etc perhaps accidently inserted in the beginning or end of your of your serverside script.

Comment: @davidkonrad, the `SQL` query returns the DB table columns in an associative array. Then the array is transformed into json i) So is there any possibility of malformed json ? ii) If it works in Chrome, shouldn't it work in FF too ?

Comment: Instead of questioning me, why not inspect your code? :) Obviously your serverside script passes malformed JSON. it is not a question about "possibility" but a fact. Have you tried testing the response in lets say JSONLint? There can be dozens of reasons for why it is going wrong, but is has nothing to do with the browser, dataTables nor the dataType on the AJAX request. As said before, my guess is that the response is enriched with orphans produced somewhere in the serverside script.